# Accessing a type member multiple time in shortest possible code form

Tags: swift

Can I write following lines of code in more short form?

Long

```
self.settings.style.buttonBarBackgroundColor = .white
self.settings.style.buttonBarItemBackgroundColor = .white
self.settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor = selectedColor
```

Short

```
var st = self.settings.style
st.buttonBarBackgroundColor = .white
st.buttonBarItemBackgroundColor = .white
st.selectedBarBackgroundColor = selectedColor
```

Ideally something like this:

```
self.settings.style {
    .buttonBarBackgroundColor = .white
    .buttonBarItemBackgroundColor = .white
    .selectedBarBackgroundColor = selectedColor
}
```

Comment: Abbreviate `Background` as `BG`? How short do you want the code? Why does it need to be shorter?

Comment: The settings object is a third party class. I can not modify it.

Comment: You're just asking for a reference to `self.settings.style`, right?

Comment: I don't recommend using abbreviations. It makes the code harder to read and maintain for anyone else or your future self who has forgotten the mental map of abbreviation to real meaning. Also do you want less per line but are ok with more lines?

Comment: Note that you don't need to declare st as variable to change its properties

Comment: Btw Xcode auto completes it for you. You don't need to write all of it. Longer and well described is better.